# Wordpress Custom post not showing in Dashedboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create custom post in WordPress. I register post by the code  like below. code are running. But Menu is not showing in Dashedboard.

```
<?php
function app_theme_custom_posts () {
    register_post_type('prime', array(
    'label' => 'Prime',
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Primes',
        'singular_name' => 'Prime',
        ),
        'public' => 'true', 
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt',  
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields'),
        ));
}
add_action('init','app_theme_custom_posts');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<?php
function app_theme_custom_posts () {
    register_post_type('prime', array(
    'labels' => array(
          'name' => __('Primes'),
          'singular_name' => __('Prime'),
          'add_new' => __('New Prime)'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-images-alt',  
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields'),
        ));
}
add_action('init','app_theme_custom_posts');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for re-write the code. But showing Parse error in line 13

Comment: The only thing i can think of at this point is changing has_archive to true because this is the only line different from my working code. If you use has_archive = true then you need to add after it- 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),